# calling controller subclass from a php script

Tags: php, curl, subclass

when I call from a php script a php controller page like:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://site.com/admin/ImportController.php");
```

`ImportContoller` is a subclass of `PageController`: `ImportController` extends `PageController`

I'm getting the error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'PageController' not found in /home/public_html/admin/ImportController.php on line 8
```

Is a call like this possible? How?

Comment: Is `PageController.php` included in `ImportController.php`? If it was called via a `require_once()` somewhere else under normal circumstances, it may not have been included here when you call `ImportController` directly

Answer (score 0):

Just add:
require_once("PageController.php");
If  it will be used any other way then require_once will not be included and in your case it will be included.